# Why do we have to prove the totallity of functions?

Tags: functions, logic, definition, first-order-logic

While studying first-order theories (or logic in general) I often encountered the phrase that "it was not possible to show that a function $f$ is total" (i.e. defined everywhere) and hence I deduced that there is a need to show this everytime when I deal with a function.

But what does this even mean? Why should a function not be total? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) states that *total function* is just a synonym for *function*.

So when the language $L$ of my first-order theory $T$ contains a function symbol $f$, does "showing totallity" mean that I have to prove $(\forall x)[(\exists y)[f(x)=y]]$? Answers to my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257597/does-using-constant-symbols-in-a-first-order-theory-implicitely-induce-an-existe) suggested that this is indeed not necessary as this can be proven from the usual axioms and deduction rules:

> Let $f$ be a function symbol. Then $f(u)$ is a term. Using the reflexivity of $=$, we can deduce $f(u)=f(u)$. This allows to deduce $(\exists y)[f(u)=y]$ and finally by introduction of universal quantification also $(\forall x)[(\exists y)[f(x)=y]]$.

So my question is: what does it exactly mean to prove that a function is total and why is there a need to do so? I ask this question because the totallity of a function was mentioned several times while discussing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272734/diagonalization-on-turing-machines-and-proofs-where-does-the-argument-fail) other question of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L=\{+,\cdot, 1, 0\}$ be the language of arithmetic, i.e. $+,\cdot$ are binary function symbols and $0,1$ are constant symbols. Consider the Gödelization $\overline\bullet:\mathbb{N}\to T^L$ which assigns to a natural number $n$ the $L$-Term $\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}$

Let $\Phi$ be a set of $L$-sentences and $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a function. We say that $\Phi$ represents $f$ if there is a $L$-formula $\varphi_f(x,y)$ s.t.
$$f(n)=m \qquad\text{iff}\qquad\Phi\models\varphi_f(\overline n, \overline m)$$

In particular, if $\Phi$ represents $f$, then for all $n$ there is $m$ s.t. $\Phi\models\varphi_f(\overline n, \overline m)$. This does however not imply that $\Phi\models\forall x \exists y \varphi_f(x,y)$. If the later holds, we say that $\Phi$ proves that $f$ is total.

For illustration let us look at the following results:

**Theorem:** Let $\Phi=PA$ be the theory of [Peano Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic), then $\Phi$ represents every computable function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.

So in particular it represents the [Goodstein Fuction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem#Sequence_length_as_a_function_of_the_starting_value) $G$ by a formula $\varphi_G$, however we have

**Kirby Paris Theorem:** $PA$ does not prove that $G$ is total, i.e
$$PA\not\models\forall x \exists y \varphi_G(x,y)$$

Comment: So we only have to prove the totallity of implicitely defined functions? And further, that we can prove $f(\bar n)$ makes sense for all $n\in \Bbb N$ is not enough to prove the universal case $f(x)$, is because $\bar n$ is always a standard integer and there are always non-standard integers where this might fail?

Answer (score 0):

Often when we do mathematics it is assumed that whenever we talk about a function, it is assumed to be a total function, which means that $f(x)$ is defined for any $x \in X$.  But functions can in fact not be total (if they are not total, they are called partial functions).

Now, in logic we require that any interpretation of a function symbol is a total function ... which is for various reasons we need not get into. So: when you suggest an interpretation for a function symbol, you really need to check that it is indeed defined for every object in the domain.

Thus, for example, if I suggest that some function symbol $f$ be interpreted as the predecessor function, and I declare the domain to be the natural numbers, then I am in trouble, since the predecessor function would not be defined for $0$.  And note that being able to prove $\forall x \exists y f(x) = y$ does not help: that is a syntactical sentence that you are able to prove ... the predecessor of 0 in the domain of the natural numbers still does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

This is my try to summarize my understanding of the topic that I got from the answers to my question.

The need for showing the totallity of a function does only arise when the function is *implicitely defined*. This excludes functions given by function symbols because these induce an explicit definition by the semantic interpretation.

For example, in first-order PA, one can ask if for any $x$ there is a $y$ with $Sy=x$. If so, then one could define a function $f(x)=y$ with the property $Sf(x)=x$. This is of course not the case. More generally, for some formula $\varphi$ one can ask if for any $x$ there is a $y$ so that $\varphi(x,y)$. It could be possible that we can be proven from a meta point of view that

$$\text{for all $n\in\Bbb N$ there is some $m\in \Bbb N$ so that $\varphi(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_n,\underbrace{1+\cdots +1}_m)$}.$$

It seems that this proves the statement for all natural numbers. But still, there could be a model of PA with some non-standard integer $x$ for which there is no $y$ so that $\varphi(x,y)$. So, even tho we could define a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ with $\varphi(x,f(x))$, we cannot prove its existence in PA, because PA does not describe the standard integers $\Bbb N$ but all models that satisfy its axioms. And we know there are many.